# div through the files

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a file application.html.erb that, as far as I understand, appears on all my pages. In that application I have a navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <%= link_to "MyGym", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><%=link_to "About", about_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

That navbar has a gradient in the background specified in my application.css.scss file:

```
.navbar {
    // gradient from uiGradients by _ighosh
    background: #52c234;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #061700, #52c234);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #061700, #52c234); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

    border: none;
  }
```

On my home page home.html.erb I have the page-header that looks like below. It appears right under my navbar:

```
<div class="text-center home-callout">
  <h1>MY GYM</h1>
  <h2>Book your place, don't miss the class!</h2>
</div>
```

I would like that gradient to apply to navbar only on all other pages but on the main page I would like it to apply to navbar and my home-callout. As it is horizontal background applying it both to navbar and my home-callout doesn't work (it starts with dark, ends with light green in navbar and then starts with dark green again below it). It looks for me that either I need a div through two pages or to override my navbar once in my home page. I hope I explained clearly my idea, could you help me with that?

Comment: I looks like you need to put the .home-callout div INSIDE the nav tag and not below it.

Comment: @arieljuod it still gives me just two divs with the same class - so my gradient two times (twice: from dark to light and again from dark to light). It's not that effect...

Comment: Post a fiddle of the problem using jsfiddle or codepen, it's easier to understand and to suggest solutions

Comment: I don't know what "fiddle of the problem" is. I'm using cloud9, will it be good? What exactly is not clear in my problem - maybe I can just clarify the post...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ you can put your html and css to play around with, paste here a link of a fiddle reproducing your problem

Comment: here's the .home-callout inside the nav tag https://jsfiddle.net/06sfrux5/

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. Now I see. The point is that my home page (so .home-callout) is define in seperate file home.html.erb as I need that to appear only on the home page. I edited the post already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If having the .home-callout div inside the nav tag solves your problem, you can use yield to have a placeholder inside nav and only fill that in in the home.html.erb view.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <%= link_to "MyGym", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><%=link_to "About", about_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= yield(:inside_nav) -%>
  </nav>
```

notice the last line before closing the nav tag

And inside yout home.html.erb you set the content:

```
<%= content_for :inside_nav do -%>
  <div class="text-center home-callout">
    <h1>MY GYM</h1>
    <h2>Book your place, don't miss the class!</h2>
  </div>
<%- end -%>
//the rest of the template
```

Rails's templating system will handle that and put the code inside nav when it's present or just ignore the yield if not defined.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you.